# dispatch_queue_t as instance variable in C++ class

Tags: c++, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, objective-c++

I am trying to write a [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) wrapper around [grand-central-dispatch](/questions/tagged/grand-central-dispatch) (GCD) queue.

I have it like this in header file

```
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

namespace myspace {

class Queue 
{

public: 
    Queue(dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue);
private:
    dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue_;
}
}
```

The counterpart of header is .mm file with implementation.

I import Queue.h into some other pure C++ file and when linking I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
   "myspace::Queue::Queue(dispatch_queue_s*)", referenced from:
        myspace::NiceClass::CreateOneMoreQueue() in NiceClass.o
```

In NiceClass I create a new Queue:

```
Queue *queue = new Queue(dispatch_get_main_queue());
```

I'm stuck with this one. It seems like I can't do it like this. I could change `dispatch_queue_t` to `void*` and it works like that but I lose type information and get lots of casts.

I would appreciate any idea.

EDIT: this is implementation in Queue.mm. Memory management and other details omitted.

```
Queue::Queue(dispatch_queue_t dispatchQueue) 
{
    dispatchQueue_ = dispatchQueue;
    if (dispatchQueue_ == NULL) {
        dispatchQueue_ = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    }
}

void Queue::AddMessage(Handler *handler, Context *context)
{
    Message *msg = new Message;
    msg->phandler = handler;
    msg->context = context;
    dispatch_async(dispatchQueue_, ^{
        handler->ProcessMessage(msg);
    });
}
```

EDIT2: Here is a test project which fails for me [zip 32k](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57813900/test_cpp.zip)

Comment: Can you show the implementation?

Comment: do you actually link with the implementation?

Comment: @Angew I have added implementation to question

Comment: The implementation of Queue is not in namespace `myspace`

Comment: @sp2danny I should. Queue.mm is in compile sources in target build phases.

Comment: I have implemented what you are trying to do. You may find that passing std::shared_ptr<> to your contexts and handlers will prevent memory problems, for example when your context goes out of scope while there is is an outstanding message destined for it.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! 5 years ago! For anyone who stumbles across this now!

If myspace is a 'cpp'(Pure C++) file and Queue is a 'mm'(ObjC++) file, you will have linker failures across the language barrier when passing "dispatch" objects as they are NSObjects in ObjC++.

Change both sides to '.mm' and it should resolve the linker issues.

Answer (score 0):

add these lines:

```
namespace myspace {
....
}
```

around the implementation of

```
Queue::....
```

Comment: Still have the same problem

Comment: Is Queue.mm actually ticked in the 'include in build' window for this target?

Comment: Yes, I have checked that

Comment: I have added a test project to the question.

Comment: Interesting. If you change the extension of Queue.mm to Queue.cc, it compiles correctly.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Though if it is some other cocoa touch class it fails with other errors. Another point is that if you create instance of Queue in some other .mm file it works fine. Fails only if you create instance in .cc